# How to show uploaded file on the webpage with download option?

Tags: asp.net

I am uploading a file by using file upload control. After successful upload, when I am viewing that page then at that time I want to show that uploaded file on the page which will have the options to download it too.

Comment: Have you even tried anything? Did you do any searchs to find similar code?

Comment: This post can be closed as "unclear" or "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the path and filename with extension, that's all.

```
       <a id="A1" href='path/filename' runat="server" target="_blank">
      <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Text='filename'>
       </asp:Label>
      </a>
```