# Save a file from SQL Database on button click using Linq in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

This is my first time doing something like this, After doing a large amount of research i still cannot find what i am looking for.

Pretty much what i have is a Attachments table in my SQL database and users can store any type of file in it (Eg. PDF, Images, Word Files.... what ever they want to)

All that i want is When a user Clicks on a button in my Webpage What ever file they have stored in the database should be retrieved and saved on the users local machine (after the Save Dialog appears).

I dont want to use gridViews and all sorts of funny Objects,

Just a Simple button click --> get data --> Save Dialog appears --> and save to the local machine.

I am using ASP.NET, C# and Linq to retrieve the Data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a quick addition, a user may only store 1 attachment in the database

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of file in attachments table?? are you saving the file path or what??

if you are saving the file path you can direclty write

```
Responce.Redirect(filepath);
```

which will download the file and saved to local machine.

Comment: The path is not being save, in the DB i have Column named "Attachments" which is a (Image) type and a column named "FileName" which just stores the FileName(varchar)

The Attachment gets converted to Binary then the Binary Data is just being saved in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Read this article
[How to show uploaded file on the webpage with download option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327234/how-to-show-uploaded-file-on-the-webpage-with-download-option/10327460#10327460)

```
<a id="A1" href='path/filename' runat="server" target="_blank">
  <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Text='filename'>
   </asp:Label>
  </a>
```

Comment: I have the correct code now, Thank you for the replies guys.

I will post my answer once i am able to answer my own question :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    var imageFile = (from i in db.Attachments
             where i.IncidentActionID == _tempAction.IncidentActionsID
             select i).FirstOrDefault();


Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + imageFile.FileName + "");
Response.BinaryWrite(imageFile.Attachments);
Response.End();
```